# How could this address access violation?

Tags: c++, exception

Currently, there is one exception thrown from program written by C++, and running under windows.

here is the min dump information in the logs.

```
08/12/15 04:37:19 I New Information for UID 2d936a, FloorLoc F1505
08/12/15 04:37:19 E >>>>> EXCEPTION: Access Violation while trying to read address 20203567 
[Fault address:  004AF945 01:000AE945  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySystems\WPR.exe 00400000] <<<<<
Call stack:
Load addr  Address   Frame     Logical addr  Module
00400000   004AF945  0588F8CC  0001:000AE945 C:\Program Files (x86)\MySystems\WPR.exe  
00400000   004A89A4  0588FAEC  0001:000A79A4 C:\Program Files (x86)\MySystems\WPR.exe
```

According to the logical addr and `.map` file, I can find the codes where this exception thrown.

```
if (TempMSE->m_elem == NULL)
{
    TempMSE->m_elem = new Element(element);
    TempMSE->m_elem->SetLocation(FloorLoc);
    LoggerInfo("New Information for UID %x, FloorLoc %s", Id, FloorLoc.ToString(buf));
}

TempMSE->m_elem->SetValue0(CIN_0, 0); // this exception is thrown here!!! through logical address 0001:000AE945
```

It seems that the `m_elem` gets one address from `new` operator, and there is NO exception for `SetLocation` function calling. Also the following log output correctly.

**Why there is one exception thrown from `SetValue0`?** Here is function `SetValue0`

```
void SetValue0(INDEX idx, DWORD val)    
{ 
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < MAX_INDEX){
        if(val != m_Info[idx]) 
        { 
            m_Info[idx] = val;  
        } 
    }
}
```

The `m_Info` is one array variable in the `Element`, and its size is `MAX_INDEX`.

On the other side, the address `0x20203567` seems one readable address, how could it be read violation?

**Edit**

Add more information here

```
class Element {
    // other function here...

private:
    FloorLocation   m_FloorLoc;
    DWORD   m_Info[MAX_INDEX];
    bool            m_Dirty;
};

Element::Element(const Element& elem) {
    m_FloorLoc = elem.m_FloorLoc;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_INDEX; ++i)
       m_Info[i] = elem.m_Info[i];
    m_Dirty = elem.m_Dirty;
}

class FloorLocation {
    // other function here...
private:
    FloorId m_floorloc;
};

FloorLocation::FloorLocation( const FloorLocation& loc )
{
    memset(&m_floorloc, ' ', 8); // space filled

    if(loc.m_floorloc.id[0] != 0)
    {
        memcpy(m_floorloc.id, loc.m_floorloc.id, 8);

        // eliminate nulls
        for(int ndx=0; ndx < 8; ndx++)
        {
            if(m_floorloc.id[ndx] == 0)
                m_floorloc.id[ndx]=' ';
        }
    }
}

typedef struct {
    char id[8];
} FloorId;
```

Comment: This could happen if `TempMSE` or `TempMSE->m_elem` is not a valid address, or dangling pointer.  _e.g._ unintialised or deleted and not set to NULL, or if `m_elem` was trashed in a buffer overrun somewhere else inside the object..

Comment: "20203567" looks like ASCII characters. Did you check that the `m_elem` pointer points to (writable) RAM instead of some readonly const data?

Comment: @harper, you mean to check the pointer return by `new Element`?

Comment: Don't you have access to a debugger?

Comment: @paddy, even if the m_elem` is dangling pointer, it just get one new address from `new` operator, which confuse me.

Comment: No it doesn't.  If it's dangling, that code to create a new one doesn't execute because it's not NULL.

Comment: @skyking, unfortunately, this exception is thrown in customer site. I can not reproduce it in my local lab. I just analysis it from min dump and codes.

Comment: @zangw That's bad, but you could still make use of the debugger to pinpoint the exact location of the crash for example, given that you have the same (possibly unstripped) executable. You don't need to settle for a vague location of being somewhere in that function.

Comment: You should show the constructor for `Element` and the exact declaration for `m_Info`

Comment: @SergeBallesta, more information has added into quesiton

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of questions are a little hard to answer.  I gave some ideas in comments, which I'll elaborate on here.  Here are the kinds of things I look for when I have these sorts of crash logs with no other leads.

An access violation on read at that location suggests one of the following:

- `TempMSE` is not a valid pointer, and the exception is thrown when attempting to get `m_elem` from it;
- `TempMSE->m_elem` is not valid, and the exception is thrown inside `SetValue0` when attempting to test the value of `m_Info[idx]`.

In the latter case, this could occur if you delete `TempMSE->m_elem` somewhere but don't set it to NULL.  If another thread is responsible for that delete, perhaps you have a race condition here where it's about to be set to NULL, but this code is executed first.

Another possibility is that either `TempMSE` or `TempMSE->m_elem` get corrupted somewhere along the way.  This could be the result of a buffer overrun inside `TempMSE` (if you have arrays), or basically any sort of undefined behaviour that occurs near these pointers in memory.  If `TempMSE` is on the stack, then look for any potential trouble there.

I don't want to fill this answer with other kinds of speculation (like heap corruption), but hopefully it gives you some avenues to try.  The basic list of common culprits is this:

- coding error (not initialising or resetting a value)
- threading issues, race conditions...
- undefined behaviour or overruns trashing data

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I can't say what is actually wrong, but I would disassemble the code at `0x004AF945` - and several instructions before, and try to understand what part of the failing function that is.

As pointed out in one of the comments, the address that the fault happens at is suspiciously looking like `'C#  '`, which makes me think that somewhere a string is overflowing somewhere...

This is just a guess, but I suspect `TempMSE->m_elem` is what contains the value `0x20203567`, and thus is NOT `NULL` when it tries to access it, meaning no logging is performed. [Obviously this is based on what code you have shown so far, and if there is logging before/after that show this is not the case, my second guess is that `m_info` is somehow wrong...

Comment: (little endian) `20203567` is `"c5  "`, not `"c#  "`.